# Best models to use for inference on very small dataset n = 24

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, inference, small-sample

I am working on a very small dataset that contains 2 years' worth of monthly data. With a lot of independent variables (approx 50).

All of the data are continuous numeric data including the dependent variable.
I want to analyze the influence of the IV's on the DV. I am not interested in making actual predictions.

I have already performed a linear correlation analysis. My next step was to use a Multiple Regression model to analyze the effect of all variables on the DV. However, as you might expect the model performed very poorly. Even after handling multi-colinearity.

I basically want to be able to make suggestions to increase/decrease the DV based on the data that I have.

Besides linear correlation analysis, what other methods/models would be suitable for this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bayesian methods are especially useful for small datasets. I would recommend them here, and strongly suggest using informative priors. I'd also note that since you have time series data, you should probably incorporate the time dependence in your models.

Comment: I agree with @mkt on the possibility of using Bayesian methods. However, note that the precision of your priors can swamp the information your data gives you. You simply have very little data, and there is a high danger of overfitting. Can you say more about your data? If these are, say, aggregate sales of a whole company, perhaps you can look at sales on lower levels, like categories or products? That would give you more information to work with.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you for your response. The data consists of various KPI's of a company. Some are available on daily basis, but most of them are only available on a monthly basis. So it will not be possible to increase the samples by looking at days instead of months for example.

Comment: @mkt thank you for your response. Do you think looking at correlations is useful in this case as well?

Comment: I can't really say, we don't know enough about your problem and your data. But I think it's unlikely that correlations by themselves will tell you much.

Comment: Standard linear regression cannot fit 50 predictors with 24 cases. Do you actually understand each of these predictors separate from each other? Also, what exactly do you mean by: "I basically want to be able to make suggestions to increase/decrease the DV based on the data that I have". Also, what do you mean by: "handing multicollinearity"?

Comment: You could try a pca (principal components analysis) of the predictors, to see if they can be explained by a few factors!

Comment: @HeteroskedasticJim thank you for taking the time to reply. What I mean is that I want to be able to quantify the influence of each of these variables is on the DV. Regarding your second remark: I meant that I have removed highly correlating IV's. I do indeed understand what these variables mean on their own, they are not abstract numbers or aggregates. Just monthly data on KPI's.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you for your comment, I've thought about this as well. But I read that as a rule of thumb you want 10 samples for each dimension in the analysis. That would leave me with just 2 features to analyze in the regression model. Which defeats the purpose of doing the multi regression.